# Is there a limit to the number of items that can be added to a Drupal webform?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

**Drupal:  7.14

Webform: 7.x-3.18+4-dev**

Currently I have a total of 469 components in a Webform:

- Select options = 158
- Textfield = 115
- Number = 73
- Fieldset = 64
- Textarea = 30
- Markup = 28
- Date = 1

My problem is that I am now unable to add anymore.

Comment: Are there any error message when you try to add a new field? Or it just doesn't add?

Comment: No message at all, just the page is refreshed. I'm able to add a new component by cloning another one. Oh! also, I'm unable to change a component's weight.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation and issue queue for webform there isn't a noted limit, but it sounds like you've taken webform way further than perhaps you should. Have you considered creating a content type which anonymous users can create nodes for? Even then this is a huge number of fields.

Comment: +1, although I'm not sure if switching to a content type would solve anything. Which user is ever going to fill out 469 form fields? It sounds as if @Jhania is fixing the wrong problem.

Comment: This is an specialized and thorough survey, it really needs to have all this fields.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this problem. Edit your php.ini, and uncomment max_input_vars = 1000. Increase this as needed. This worked for me.